# check string contains gmail or yahoo or hotmail address using regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have bunch of email addresses which contains gmail, yahoo, hotmail.. etc. I need to eliminate them from email addresses using regex.

right now I am using to eliminate gmail address using like `^[a-z0-9](\.?[a-z0-9]){5,}@gmail\.com$`. But how to check yahoo, hotmail using same expression.

Comment: Seems to be unnecessary Regex day on SO...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use regex you can use something like that:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}([.]?[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})[@](gmail.com|hotmail.com|yahoo.com)
```

Comment: the thing is that ```gmail.fr |hotmail.fr|yahoo.co.uk``` would be allowed. So, is there any ```regex``` expression enabling the exclusion of any text containing ```gmail |hotmail|yahoo``` so as to be more general, and without using any ```LINQ ``` or equivalent? The aim is to use such expression within the ```<asp:RegularExpressionValidator   />```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without REGEX like:

```
HashSet<string> invalidAddresses = new HashSet<string>() { "@gmail", "@hotmail", "@yahoo" };
string emailToCheck = "someEmail@YAHOO.Com";
if (invalidAddresses.Any(i => emailToCheck.IndexOf(i, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1))
{
    //Invalid address
}
else
{
    //valid Address
}
```

if you want to filter out a `List<string>` containing email address then you can do:

```
List<string> emails = new List<string>() {"test@valid.com", "test2@something.com", "test3@hotmail.com", "test4@YAHOO.ca"};
var validEmails = emails.Where(email => !invalidAddresses
                                            .Any(i => 
                                            email.IndexOf(i, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1))
                         .ToList();
```

*(Just remember that internally LINQ will iterate/loop as well)*.

Comment: `List<string>` object that I want remove from it. not loop through it. remove all together at a time.

Comment: @James123, I have modified the code to handle a list as well.